# BrowserSync showing message 'Disconnected from BrowserSync'

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I get the message 'Disconnected from BrowserSync' almost immediately after running gulp. Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload      = browserSync.reload;


gulp.task('sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        browser: "chrome",
        proxy: "hmgcsc.app"
    });

    gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("app/**/*.html").on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("app/**/*.js").on('change', reload);
});


gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: [
                'node_modules/susy/sass' //required for sass
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));

});

gulp.task('default', ['sync']);
```

Every once in a while, it will work correctly, but never for longer than 30 seconds. The CLI acts like everything is still working correctly. It displays no errors and notifies me of file changes.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like he just fixed whatever the bug was in 2.7.1. Updating Browser-sync fixed the issue for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem (with similar configuration - I mean using proxy) and I can't figure out when did it start to act like that. What version of node/gulp/browser-sync have you installed?

Comment: I have the same configuration and I've also tried different versions for node but without success. Can't figure out what is the problem.